# TypeError: is not a function error in child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a child component which includes the code below. I pass down myData from the parent component as follows:

```
<DataList
myData={myData}
board={board}
fenHistory={fenHistory}
plyViewed={plyViewed}
classes={classes}
selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
handleListItemClick={handleListItemClick}
setFen={setFen}
setSelectedIndex={setSelectedIndex}
/>
```

But I am getting this error:

> TypeError: myData.history is not a function

myData is an object and myData.history is an array.

Edit: I think myData might actually be a function that returns an array.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
export default function moveHistory(
  myData,
  board,
  fenHistory,
  plyViewed,
  classes,
  selectedIndex,
  handleListItemClick,
  setFen,
  setSelectedIndex
) {
return (
    <Grid container direction="row">
       <Grid item xs={4}>
        <List component="nav" aria-label="secondary mailbox folders">
          {myData.history().map((each, index) => {
            if (index % 2 === 0) {
              return (
                <ListItem
                  style={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0, margin: 0 }}
                  button
                  selected={selectedIndex === index + 1}
                >
                 );
            }
          })}
        </List>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: If `myData.history` is an array why are you using it as a function: `myData.history().map()`? It should be `myData.history.map()`

Comment: Actually, I am a bit confused on whether it is a function or not. On second thoughts, it might be a function since it returns an array. So I got that wrong I think. It is the chess.history function found here: https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/README.md
Just edited my original post.

Comment: On that API docs `history()` is a function returning an array. But the TS compiler is saying that on your code `myData` has no `history` function. So you should check the exact shape of the `myData` object on the component that is consuming it or add more code to your question so we can try help you further.

Comment: Just to add, my code worked fine when the child component code was in the parent. But after extracting out, it broke. So it seems that somehow passing down the myData object (which is chess) seems to have stopped myData.history from working.

Comment: @Jon Have you tried history `myData.history.map` instead of  `myData.history().map`?

Comment: When I try to console log myData.history in the child component, I get undefined. When I try myData.history(), I get myData.history is not a function.

Comment: @Jon Please share your code, at list parent and child components.

Comment: @Join Looking at your `moveHistory` component you might be missing curly braces for destructuring: `moveHistory({myData, board, fenHistory, ... })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is when you destructuring `props`. You should add `{}` to destructure props. Something like:

```
export default function moveHistory({
  myData,
  board,
  fenHistory,
  plyViewed,
  classes,
  selectedIndex,
  handleListItemClick,
  setFen,
  setSelectedIndex
}) { 
return (
    <Grid container direction="row">
       <Grid item xs={4}>
        <List component="nav" aria-label="secondary mailbox folders">
          {myData.history().map((each, index) => {
            if (index % 2 === 0) {
              return (
                <ListItem
                  style={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0, margin: 0 }}
                  button
                  selected={selectedIndex === index + 1}
                >
                 );
            }
          })}
        </List>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: I've edited my original post because I think I made a mistake. It looks like it is a function that returns an array.

Comment: Could you show me `history()` function please?

Comment: This link shows what the history function should return: https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Just to add, my code worked fine when the child component code was in the parent. But after extracting out, it broke. So it seems that somehow passing down the myData object (which is chess) seems to have stopped myData.history from working.

Comment: @Jon When you read data in child you write `myData`. This is ok if you destructured props like `const DataList = ({myData}) => {...}`. Otherwise you should use `props.myData` right? From your question I can't see `DataList` declaration...

Comment: @Giovaani Esposito, I've added the arguments code in so you can see what is passed.

Comment: @Jon ok now I see your error. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hey, that worked, thanks! I was looking in the completely wrong place. I'm a bit confused though. I have other child components where I used props as the argument. Then I had access to all the arguments using props.whatever. But in this case a {} was required. Is it better to remove all those arguments in the child component and just put props in there, then use props.myData.history() etc?

Comment: @Jon I would say yes (too much props) but is your chioce. For me is always mor eclear `props.myData` because when I read the code I immediately understand that myData comes from props. But I repeat is your choice

Comment: I will try that as it reduces line height and makes it clear where myData came from, as you suggested.

As a side issue, I am getting a linting error on the myData.History line: "Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function." What would you do about that?

Comment: This problem is connected to the fact that `map` function wants to return always something. In your code, `map` returns only if `if (index % 2 === 0)`. You should add `else return null` (I don't know if null is correct but you got the point...)

Comment: Thanks. I will try that!

Comment: Error gone! I learned many things from your answers. Great help. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help you. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way and check `history` is not undefined before map on it:

```
 export default function moveHistory({
  myData,
  board,
  fenHistory,
  plyViewed,
  classes,
  selectedIndex,
  handleListItemClick,
  setFen,
  setSelectedIndex
}) {
return (
    <Grid container direction="row">
       <Grid item xs={4}>
        <List component="nav" aria-label="secondary mailbox folders">
          {myData.history && myData.history().map((each, index) => {
            if (index % 2 === 0) {
              return (
                <ListItem
                  style={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0, margin: 0 }}
                  button
                  selected={selectedIndex === index + 1}
                >
                 );
            }
          })}
        </List>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: That allowed the page to render, but the myData.history was not being displayed.

Comment: Based on your comment which you have said that in console log shows undefined, It seems history have not data!

Comment: Yes, but the code was working before I refactored into a child component. So why would it break now? Perhaps a solution could be to have an if statement to only show if myData.history returns data. But why would it say myData.history() is not a function just because it returns nothing?

Comment: @Jon Because it doesn't have data, `javascript` knows that as an undefined variable which doesn't clear its type. So you can't use it as an function, array or other types. Please see this link :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: @Jon I updated the code, please see it again.

Comment: Your suggestion to add the {} was what was missing as also mentioned by Giovanni, so thank you for that.